# Is there any other option rather than Pyzbar to decode object return by cap.read()?

Tags: python, zbar

I am trying to decode object return by cap.read() using pyzbar but it is giving an error.my code is:

```
    while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    decodedObject = decode(frame)
```

This code is giving an error:

```
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'F:\New Volume\PycharmProjects\trial\venv\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\libzbar-64.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax
```

I have tried a lot to resolve this error. I want to know, is there any other alternative rather than `pyzbar` to decode object return by `cap.read()`?

Comment: What is `cap.read()` from?

Comment: The error means that the DLL cannot be found, try reinstall `pyzbar` module.

Comment: @TimRoberts cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

Comment: @acw1668 I reinstall pyzbar module still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you reinstall it in your Pycharm virtual environment?

Comment: @acw1668 yes, I have reinstalled it in virtual environment.

Comment: Then I don't know why because I don't have the issue when running your code.

Comment: @acw1668 is any other option for decoding object return by cap.read() rather than pyzbar?

Comment: You may search in pypi.org.  Did you check whether the DLL is actually missing inside the directory?

Comment: @acw1668 no, I did not check because I do not know how to check this.

Comment: The error message has the full path of the DLL.